# reading terminal in python not the same

Tags: python

```
import os
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
#os.chdir("..")
cmd=["ls","*.py"]

try:
    p=Popen(cmd,stdout=PIPE,universal_newlines=True,shell=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Exception:\t{e}")
for line in p.stdout:
    print(line,end=" ")
p.stdout.close()
return_code=p.wait()
```

I am trying to get `ls` all python files in my server, however whenever I am writing the output which should be all .py files only, I am getting every file there, what am I doing wrong.
I tried `ls *.py` in server terminal and it works fine,however in script not working

Comment: Not a solution, but why are you using `Popen` instead of `run`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use "ls *.py" as a command

```
import os
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
#os.chdir("..")
cmd=["ls *.py"]

try:
    p=Popen(cmd,stdout=PIPE,universal_newlines=True,shell=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Exception:\t{e}")
for line in p.stdout:
    print(line,end=" ")
p.stdout.close()
return_code=p.wait()
```

Comment: this works, but in docs the used list elements to show spaces

Comment: @Piggydog When you use `shell=True`, the command is given to the shell as a single string.

Comment: If you use a list, it just sends the first element to the shell.

Comment: Although the documentation doesn't seem to mention this.